# TypeError: 'QueryDict' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, sqlite

the error on the title showed to me in this django code

views.py :

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import userdata
def signinView(request) :
    all_users = userdata.objects.all()
    return render(request,'signin.html',{'all_items':all_users})

def adduser(request) :
    c = request.POST('username')
    d = request.POST('password')
    new_item = userdata(username=c, password=d)
    new_item.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/signin/')
```

urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from signin.views import signinView, adduser
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('signin/',signinView),

   path('adduser/',adduser)
]
```

signin.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>sign up</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="form-inline" action="/adduser/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="userame">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
    <label for="inputPassword2" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2" placeholder="Password" name="password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2" value="add">sign up</button>
</form>
<!--<ul>
<li>
    <p>username password</p>
</li>
</ul>
-->
<ul>
    {% for user_data in all_items %}
    <li>{{ user_data.username}} : {{ user_data.password }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

what should I do to fix the error?
the app should print on the screen the username and passwords and let the users add the user name and password of them, I just start with Django and i be happy from help i am try to write enough to be available to send the post, again, I need this help but its not critical for now

Comment: Can you share a stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `c = request.POST('username')` with:

```
c = request.POST.get('username') # with this option c will be set to None automatically if username key is not present in post request
```

or

```
c = request.POST['username'] # if username is not present in the post this will throw an KeyError
```

and also for the next line as well; As `QueryDict` it's a *dictionary like* object (and hence not callable)

Comment: but then it shows me :NOT NULL constraint failed: signin_userdata.username

Comment: Seems like the `c` (which should hold the `username`) is empty. Do you have a `<input name="username" ...>` in your template? and also sending a `POST` request?

Comment: where in the template?

Comment: Please add your template code so that we can find the problem.

Comment: i add the template

Comment: You have `name="userame"` in your input which is missing a "**n**"; simply change it to `name="username"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205159/discussion-between-pedram-parsian-and--).